# Play framework Redirect.withSession("key" -> value) not setting mapping in the request

Tags: scala, playframework

Example code from the Scala Microservices book has a call to Redirect().withSession()

```
  def login(name: String, password: String) = Action {
if (check(name, password))
  Redirect("/auth/index").withSession("user" -> name)
else
  BadRequest("Invalid user or password") }
```

but the index method shows that the "user" key is not set in the request

```
def index = Action { implicit request =>

println(request.session.get("user"))
request.session.get("user") match {
  case Some(user) if isValidUser(user) => Ok(s"Welcome ${user}")
  case Some(user) => BadRequest(s"${user} is not a valid user")
  case None => BadRequest(
    "You are currently not logged in. \nPlease login by calling: \n" +
    "http://localhost:9000/auth/login/admin/1234")
} }
```

The println() statement shows `None`.

Why doesn't the "user" key get set in the request session?

Comment: You happen to have more information as to where the `Redirect("/auth/index").withSession("user" -> name)` is being made and ensuring that the `Action` where that is located is being called?  Everything looks right, but with only one line it is tough to judge.

Comment: Edited to show the entire calling method.

Comment: Seems right to me too.  Can you open chrome development tab using F12 and confirm, that same cookie header is being sent over both requests?